# How to generate random names in AWS S3

Tags: php

I have a php code to upload files to AWS S3.

When a user uploads a file, it is uploaded with the same name. The problem is that if a user uploads a file with an existing name, the file is overwritten.

How can I change the name of the uploaded file with a random name that does not repeat?

Comment: Use a timestamp in the filename

Comment: generate a random character, append it to the filename, check if the file exists, if so, add a new random character, etc.  or generate a UUID and append that to the filename, or name the file the uploading username with the date and time prefixed

Comment: I removed AWS tags as the question has nothing to do with AWS

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = 'whatever name you want-' . uniqid();
```

This will append a UUID to your name and *almost* guarantee uniqueness.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid

Or:

```
$name = 'whatever name you want-' . microtime();
```

Which will give you a unique name per microsecond.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

If spaces are a problem, you'll need to do a tiny string manipulation to remove it from microtime:

```
$name = str_replace(' ', '', $micro);
```